# Midrash on the sale of the Machpelah Cave

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, transactions, abraham

A few days ago I saw in a library book a midrash on the sale of the Machpelah Cave. The midrash detailed the names of the four witnesses who signed their names on the deed. Unfortunately, I returned the book already and can't remember where that midrash is located. Does anyone know the location of that midrash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're perhaps referring to the [*Sefer Hayashar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_haYashar_(midrash)) [on Chayei Sarah](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaYashar_(midrash)%2C_Book_of_Genesis%2C_Chayei_Sara.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

> ויכתוב אברהם את הדבר הזה בספר ויחתום, ויעד ארבעה עדים. ואלה שמות העדים: אמיגל בן אבישוע החתי אליחורף בן אשונה החוי, עדון בן אחירע הגרדי, עקדיל בן אבודיש הצידוני.

> And Abraham wrote this matter in a scroll and signed, and four witnesses witnessed. And these are the names of the witnesses: Amigal son of Abishua the Hittite, Elichoref son of Ashuna the Hiwite, Idon son of Ahira the Gardite, Akadil son of Abudis the Zidonite.

Comment: Yeah, that's the one. Thanks!